# how to send input value to console log data in react hook form

Tags: reactjs

I have created small react application. I developed edit and update component, I get all data from API and assigned all values in input fields while I am submitting did not get value from console.log(data). How to render input values from onSubmit data am using react hook form could you please check and solve this issues.

```
`import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { AES, enc } from "crypto-js";
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel";
import $ from "jquery";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
  AccordionItemHeading,
  AccordionItemButton,
  AccordionItemPanel,
} from "react-accessible-accordion";
import Header from "../Header";
import Footer from "../Footer";
import { decryptedAccessToken, encryptedAccessToken } from "../../Token";
const EditQuote = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.id;
  const [productCode, setProductCode] = useState("");
  const [productValues, setProductValues] = useState([]);
  const [products, setproducts] = useState([]);
  const [getQuotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [decryptedAccessToken]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/get/quotesbyID/" + id,
        {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },
        }
      );
      const data = response.data;

      setQuotes(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange",
    reValidateMode: "all",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);

    const encryptedAccessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    const secret_key = "4d3a23fba54bbef1e14dd44ba9591612";
    if (encryptedAccessToken) {
      const decryptedAccessToken = AES.decrypt(
        encryptedAccessToken,
        secret_key
      ).toString(enc.Utf8);

      fetch("https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/update_quotes/" + id, {
        method: "PUT",
        // body: JSON.stringify(responseData),
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())

        .then((response) => {
          $(".successDiv").html('<p class="result">Data added</p>');

          setTimeout(() => {
            $(".successDiv").hide();
            reset();
          }, 300);
        });
      // console.log(responseData)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      <Header />
      <div className="page-header" id="add-account">
        <div>
          <h2 className="main-content-title tx-24 mg-b-5">Edit Quote</h2>
          <ol className="breadcrumb">
            <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
              Dashboard / Edit Quote
            </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="justify-content-center">
            {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-icon-text">
         <a href='/account/add-account'> <i className="fe fe-download-cloud me-2"></i><FaPlus/> Add Account</a>
        </button> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="tasks">
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Accordion preExpanded={["a"]}>
            <AccordionItem uuid="a">
              <AccordionItemHeading>
                <AccordionItemButton>Quote Section 1</AccordionItemButton>
              </AccordionItemHeading>
              <AccordionItemPanel>
                <Row className="mb-3">
                  {/* <h4 className='heading'>Account Information</h4> */}

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Code"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Code"
                        name="product_code"
                        value={getQuotes.product_code}
                        {...register("product_code")}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingSelect"
                      className="dropDown"
                      label="Quote Shipment"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Quote Shipment"
                        name="quote_shipment"
                        value={getQuotes.quote_shipment}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Name"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Account"
                        name="product_account"
                        value={getQuotes.product_account}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Supplier"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Supplier"
                        name="product_supplier"
                        value={getQuotes.product_supplier}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Description"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Description"
                        name="product_description"
                        value={getQuotes.product_description}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Family"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Family"
                        name="product_family"
                        value={getQuotes.product_family}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Price Basis"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Price Basis"
                        name="product_price_basis"
                        value={getQuotes.product_price_basis}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product price type"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product price type"
                        name="product_price_type"
                        value={getQuotes.product_price_type}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Product Port Of Loading"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Product Port Of Loading"
                        name="product_port_of_loading"
                        value={getQuotes.product_port_of_loading}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Gross Air Dried Typical"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Gross Air Dried Typical"
                        name="gross_air_dried_typical"
                        value={getQuotes.gross_air_dried_typical}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Gross Air Dried Min"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Gross Air Dried Min"
                        name="gross_air_dried_min"
                        value={getQuotes.gross_air_dried_min}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Gross Air Dried Max"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Gross Air Dried Max"
                        name="gross_air_dried_max"
                        value={getQuotes.gross_air_dried_max}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Gross As Recieved Min"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Gross As Recieved Min"
                        name="gross_as_recieved_min"
                        value={getQuotes.gross_as_recieved_min}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Gross As Recieved Max"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Gross As Recieved Max"
                        name="gross_as_recieved_max"
                        value={getQuotes.gross_as_recieved_max}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Net As Recieved Min"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Net As Recieved Min"
                        name="net_as_recieved_min"
                        value={getQuotes.net_as_recieved_min}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Moisture Typical"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Moisture Typical"
                        name="moisture_typical"
                        value={getQuotes.moisture_typical}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Moisture Minimum"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Moisture Minimum"
                        name="moisture_minimum"
                        value={getQuotes.moisture_minimum}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Ash Typical"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Ash Typical"
                        name="ash_typical"
                        value={getQuotes.ash_typical}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Ash Minimum"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Ash Minimum"
                        name="ash_minimum"
                        value={getQuotes.ash_minimum}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Ash Maximum"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Ash Maximum"
                        name="ash_maximum"
                        value={getQuotes.ash_maximum}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Volatile Matter Typical"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Volatile Matter Typical"
                        name="volatile_matter_typical"
                        value={getQuotes.volatile_matter_typical}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Volatile Matter Minimum"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Volatile Matter Minimum"
                        name="volatile_matter_minimum"
                        value={getQuotes.volatile_matter_minimum}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Volatile Matter Maximum"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Volatile Matter Maximum"
                        name="volatile_matter_maximum"
                        value={getQuotes.volatile_matter_maximum}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Fixed Carbon By Difference"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Fixed Carbon By Difference"
                        name="fixed_carbon_by_difference"
                        value={getQuotes.fixed_carbon_by_difference}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Fixed Carbon Typical"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Fixed Carbon Typical"
                        name="fixed_carbon_typical"
                        value={getQuotes.fixed_carbon_typical}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>

                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Fixed Carbon Minimum"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Fixed Carbon Minimum"
                        name="fixed_carbon_minimum"
                        value={getQuotes.fixed_carbon_minimum}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                </Row>
              </AccordionItemPanel>
            </AccordionItem>
            <AccordionItem>
              <AccordionItemHeading>
                <AccordionItemButton>Quote Section 2</AccordionItemButton>
              </AccordionItemHeading>
              <AccordionItemPanel>
                <div className="row">
                  <Form.Group as={Col} md="6">
                    <FloatingLabel
                      controlId="floatingInput"
                      label="Moisture Typical"
                      className="mb-3"
                    >
                      <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Moisture Typical"
                        name="moisture_typical"
                        value={getQuotes.moisture_typical}
                      />
                    </FloatingLabel>
                  </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary add-quote">
                    Save
                  </button>
                  {/* <input type="submit"  className="btn btn-primary add-quote" value='Save'/> */}
                  <div className="successDiv"></div>
                </div>{" "}
              </AccordionItemPanel>
            </AccordionItem>
          </Accordion>
        </Form>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditQuote;`
```